# keepout filter in ros1

Tags: costmap, layered-costmap

I have some questions about costmap theory, if you can help me.

- How we calculate the cost of each pixel for the costmap master. (sum of all layer? or average...??)
- What is the algorithm using in keepout filter and slow safety filter in NAV2. I want to use them in ROS1 so I should code the algorithme and I don't understand from the wiki the real idea behind the filters.

THank you for your help,
Best regards